# Msg 13609, Level 16, State 4, Line 4 JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '"' is found at position 447

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, azure, json.net

I have a JSON column in SQL Server table called `report_json` which I am using to query data using the below query :

```
SELECT TOP 200
    mrgpi.GPI_Code AS Genric_product_Identifier,
    bin = JSON_VALUE(d.value, '$.bin'),  
    name = JSON_VALUE(d.value, '$.name'),
    rxnorm_id = JSON_VALUE(d.value, '$.rxnorm_id')
FROM
    [dbo].[clia_report] AS cr
CROSS APPLY 
    OPENJSON(cr.report_json, '$.drugs') d
JOIN 
    [dbo].[Vu_Med_Ref_With_GPI_Upated] mrgpi ON JSON_VALUE(d.value,'$.rxnorm_id') = mrgpi.rxnorm_id
WHERE
    JSON_VALUE(d.value, '$.bin') = 'R'
```

This query was working fine, but recently I am getting this error when running it:

> Msg 13609, Level 16, State 4, Line 2
> JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '"' is found at position 447.

Please guide where I am going wrong and what should I do.

JSON is as below:

```
[
  {
    "id": 76292,
    "uuid": "0x2B0DCF8671CC11ED8C713B7BF98F6338",
    "sf_id": null,
    "sf_sync_date": null,
    "mtime": "2022-12-02T13:43:01",
    "ctime": "2022-12-01T23:02:03",
    "kit_id": 114918,
    "report_json": "{\"drugs\": {}, \"genes\": {\"MTHFR\": {\"name\": \"MTHFR\", \"type\": \"target\", \"value\": \"rs1801131 AC, rs1801133 CT\", \"hidden\": false, \"alleles\": null, \"gene_id\": 97, \"sort_key\": 0, \"description\": \"Note: MTHFR is available to providers as an optional, complimentary add-on to the RightMed Test. MTHFR is not available to patients who purchase the test online (ordered through the independent physician network).\\n\\nResiding on the minus strand of chromosome 1, the <em>MTHFR</em> gene encodes the rate-limiting enzyme methylenetetrahydrofolate reductase. This enzyme is integrally involved in the DNA synthesis pathway, specifically in the conversion of homocysteine to methionine through the methylation cycle of folic acid. Common variants in this gene, namely rs1801133 and rs1801131, can disrupt this pathway, thereby altering folic acid metabolism and/or leading to hyperhomocysteinemia. However, the American College of Medical Genetics and Genomics (ACMG) determined that <em>MTHFR</em> genotyping has m",
    "alg_input_json": "{\"cap\": \"9432670\", \"npi\": \"1669836227\", \"nys\": null, \"clia\": \"24D2109855\", \"task\": \"F72CB\", \"tube\": \"NA20221201001\", \"target\": {\"MTHFR\": {\"value\": \"rs1801131 AC, rs1801133 CT\", \"value_raw\": null, \"phenotype_raw\": null, \"review_reasons\": [], \"phenotype_title\": null, \"value_functional\": \"rs1801131 AC, rs1801133 CT\", \"phenotype_summary\": null, \"performing_site_indicator\": false}}, \"patient\": {\"dob\": \"2002-12-28\", \"name\": \"Quinn Hirschland\", \"ethnicity\": 10, \"sample_id\": null, \"identifier\": \"\"}, \"filename\": null, \"provider\": \"Dr. Neda Leonard\", \"metabolic\": {}, \"exceptions\": null, \"panel_code\": \"SG-MTHFR\", \"translator\": null, \"report_type\": null, \"sample_type\": \"DNA\", \"deidentified\": false, \"lab_comments\": \"\", \"lab_director\": \"Lee Kaplan, PhD, FACMG\", \"product_code\": \"SG-MTHFR\", \"receive_date\": \"2022-12-01\", \"report_state\": null, \"report_title\": null, \"specimen_date\": null, \"collection_date\": \"2022-11-07\", \"institution_code\": null, \"ordering_facility\": \"Rx Gene IQ LLC\", \"lab_address_line_1"
  },
  {
    "id": 76293,
    "uuid": "0xE46BEEA4726B11EDA6E6F9590B4EAE8C",
    "sf_id": null,
    "sf_sync_date": null,
    "mtime": "2022-12-02T18:06:23",
    "ctime": "2022-12-02T18:05:24",
    "kit_id": 97978,
    "report_json": "{\"drugs\": {\"Aspirin\": {\"bin\": \"X\", \"name\": \"Aspirin\", \"icons\": [], \"drug_id\": 901, \"pathway\": {\"code\": \"unknown\", \"text\": \"oneome-unclassified-do-not-use or gray drug\"}, \"targets\": [], \"loe_code\": \"4\", \"triggers\": [{\"actions\": [{\"icon_id\": null, \"action_id\": 14962, \"trigger_id\": 12050, \"application\": null, \"guideline_ids\": null, \"drug_report_icon_id\": 84, \"trigger_phenotype_id\": null, \"metabolic_phenotype_id\": null, \"custom_drug_report_text\": \"Several studies have shown that the pharmacokinetic properties, risk of aspirin related toxic events, and treatment efficacy of aspirin are not significantly impacted by CYP2C9. Preliminary evidence suggests that PEAR1 rs12041331 may modulate non-COX dependent platelet aggregation pathways, but there is no evidence to suggest an association between the variant and adverse drug events while taking aspirin. In a study with 895 Danish patients with stable coronary artery disease taking 75mg aspirin daily, patients homozygous AA or heterozygous GA fo",
    "alg_input_json": "{\"cap\": \"9432670\", \"npi\": \"1669836227\", \"nys\": null, \"clia\": \"24D2109855\", \"task\": \"832C2\", \"tube\": \"41211111710104\", \"target\": {\"F2\": {\"value\": \"rs1799963 GG\", \"value_raw\": null, \"phenotype_raw\": null, \"review_reasons\": [], \"phenotype_title\": null, \"value_functional\": \"rs1799963 GG\", \"phenotype_summary\": null, \"performing_site_indicator\": false}, \"F5\": {\"value\": \"rs6025 GG\", \"value_raw\": null, \"phenotype_raw\": null, \"review_reasons\": [], \"phenotype_title\": null, \"value_functional\": \"rs6025 GG\", \"phenotype_summary\": null, \"performing_site_indicator\": false}, \"4F2\": {\"value\": \"*1/*3\", \"value_raw\": null, \"phenotype_raw\": null, \"review_reasons\": [], \"phenotype_title\": null, \"value_functional\": \"*1/*3\", \"phenotype_summary\": null, \"performing_site_indicator\": false}, \"COMT\": {\"value\": \"rs4680 GG\", \"value_raw\": null, \"phenotype_raw\": null, \"review_reasons\": [], \"phenotype_title\": null, \"value_functional\": \"rs4680 GG\", \"phenotype_summary\": null, \"performing_site_indicator\": false}, \"DPYD\": {\""
  },
  {
    "id": 76294,
    "uuid": "0xE6EA4027726B11ED97993B7BF98F6338",
    "sf_id": null,
    "sf_sync_date": null,
    "mtime": "2022-12-02T18:06:47",
    "ctime": "2022-12-02T18:05:28",
    "kit_id": 98954,
    "report_json": "{\"drugs\": {\"Codeine\": {\"bin\": \"G\", \"name\": \"Codeine\", \"icons\": [108, 100, 103], \"drug_id\": 36, \"pathway\": {\"code\": \"prodrug\", \"text\": \"is **inactive**, its metabolites are active.\"}, \"targets\": [\"OPRM1\"], \"loe_code\": \"1A\", \"triggers\": [{\"actions\": [{\"icon_id\": 103, \"action_id\": 14915, \"trigger_id\": 12036, \"application\": null, \"guideline_ids\": \"887\", \"drug_report_icon_id\": 103, \"trigger_phenotype_id\": null, \"metabolic_phenotype_id\": null, \"custom_drug_report_text\": null}], \"drug_id\": 36, \"proceed\": true, \"sort_key\": 100049, \"conditions\": [{\"gene_id\": null, \"allele_id\": null, \"trigger_id\": 12036, \"condition_id\": 105207, \"ethnicity_id\": null, \"drug_phenotype_id\": null, \"gene_phenotype_id\": null}], \"trigger_id\": 12036, \"icon_block_level\": 0, \"guideline_block_level\": 0}, {\"actions\": [{\"icon_id\": 108, \"action_id\": 13121, \"trigger_id\": 11744, \"application\": null, \"guideline_ids\": null, \"drug_report_icon_id\": 108, \"trigger_phenotype_id\": null, \"metabolic_phenotype_id\": null, \"custom_drug_repor",
    "alg_input_json": "{\"cap\": \"9432670\", \"npi\": \"1669836227\", \"nys\": null, \"clia\": \"24D2109855\", \"task\": \"F6D02\", \"tube\": \"41220410300915\", \"target\": {\"F2\": {\"value\": \"rs1799963 GG\", \"value_raw\": null, \"phenotype_raw\": null, \"review_reasons\": [], \"phenotype_title\": null, \"value_functional\": \"rs1799963 GG\", \"phenotype_summary\": null, \"performing_site_indicator\": false}, \"F5\": {\"value\": \"rs6025 GG\", \"value_raw\": null, \"phenotype_raw\": null, \"review_reasons\": [], \"phenotype_title\": null, \"value_functional\": \"rs6025 GG\", \"phenotype_summary\": null, \"performing_site_indicator\": false}, \"4F2\": {\"value\": \"*1/*3\", \"value_raw\": null, \"phenotype_raw\": null, \"review_reasons\": [], \"phenotype_title\": null, \"value_functional\": \"*1/*3\", \"phenotype_summary\": null, \"performing_site_indicator\": false}, \"COMT\": {\"value\": \"rs4680 GG\", \"value_raw\": null, \"phenotype_raw\": null, \"review_reasons\": [], \"phenotype_title\": null, \"value_functional\": \"rs4680 GG\", \"phenotype_summary\": null, \"performing_site_indicator\": false}, \"DPYD\": {\""
  },
  {
    "id": 76295,
    "uuid": "0xF58B7ABC726B11ED9FAA3B7BF98F6338",
    "sf_id": null,
    "sf_sync_date": null,
    "mtime": "2022-12-02T18:06:47",
    "ctime": "2022-12-02T18:05:52",
    "kit_id": 98954,
    "report_json": "{\"drugs\": {}, \"genes\": {\"MTHFR\": {\"name\": \"MTHFR\", \"type\": \"target\", \"value\": \"rs1801131 AC, rs1801133 CC\", \"hidden\": false, \"alleles\": null, \"gene_id\": 97, \"sort_key\": 0, \"description\": \"Note: MTHFR is available to providers as an optional, complimentary add-on to the RightMed Test. MTHFR is not available to patients who purchase the test online (ordered through the independent physician network).\\n\\nResiding on the minus strand of chromosome 1, the <em>MTHFR</em> gene encodes the rate-limiting enzyme methylenetetrahydrofolate reductase. This enzyme is integrally involved in the DNA synthesis pathway, specifically in the conversion of homocysteine to methionine through the methylation cycle of folic acid. Common variants in this gene, namely rs1801133 and rs1801131, can disrupt this pathway, thereby altering folic acid metabolism and/or leading to hyperhomocysteinemia. However, the American College of Medical Genetics and Genomics (ACMG) determined that <em>MTHFR</em> genotyping has m",
    "alg_input_json": "{\"cap\": \"9432670\", \"npi\": \"1669836227\", \"nys\": null, \"clia\": \"24D2109855\", \"task\": \"F6D02\", \"tube\": \"41220410300915\", \"target\": {\"MTHFR\": {\"value\": \"rs1801131 AC, rs1801133 CC\", \"value_raw\": null, \"phenotype_raw\": null, \"review_reasons\": [], \"phenotype_title\": null, \"value_functional\": \"rs1801131 AC, rs1801133 CC\", \"phenotype_summary\": null, \"performing_site_indicator\": false}}, \"patient\": {\"dob\": \"2000-04-19\", \"name\": \"Abril Osiris Medina\", \"ethnicity\": 50, \"sample_id\": null, \"identifier\": \"41220410300915\"}, \"filename\": null, \"provider\": \"Dr Felipe de Jesus Ortega Zarzosa\", \"metabolic\": {}, \"exceptions\": null, \"panel_code\": \"SG-MTHFR\", \"translator\": null, \"report_type\": null, \"sample_type\": \"Buccal swab\", \"deidentified\": false, \"lab_comments\": \"\", \"lab_director\": \"Lee Kaplan, PhD, FACMG\", \"product_code\": \"SG-MTHFR\", \"receive_date\": \"2022-11-29\", \"report_state\": null, \"report_title\": null, \"specimen_date\": null, \"collection_date\": \"2022-11-17\", \"institution_code\": null, \"ordering_facil"
  },
  {
    "id": 76296,
    "uuid": "0x115ED889726C11EDBEDB3B7BF98F6338",
    "sf_id": null,
    "sf_sync_date": null,
    "mtime": "2022-12-02T18:07:43",
    "ctime": "2022-12-02T18:06:39",
    "kit_id": 98127,
    "report_json": "{\"drugs\": {\"Codeine\": {\"bin\": \"Y\", \"name\": \"Codeine\", \"icons\": [108, 93, 103], \"drug_id\": 36, \"pathway\": {\"code\": \"prodrug\", \"text\": \"is **inactive**, its metabolites are active.\"}, \"targets\": [\"OPRM1\"], \"loe_code\": \"1A\", \"triggers\": [{\"actions\": [{\"icon_id\": 103, \"action_id\": 14915, \"trigger_id\": 12036, \"application\": null, \"guideline_ids\": \"887\", \"drug_report_icon_id\": 103, \"trigger_phenotype_id\": null, \"metabolic_phenotype_id\": null, \"custom_drug_report_text\": null}], \"drug_id\": 36, \"proceed\": true, \"sort_key\": 100049, \"conditions\": [{\"gene_id\": null, \"allele_id\": null, \"trigger_id\": 12036, \"condition_id\": 105207, \"ethnicity_id\": null, \"drug_phenotype_id\": null, \"gene_phenotype_id\": null}], \"trigger_id\": 12036, \"icon_block_level\": 0, \"guideline_block_level\": 0}, {\"actions\": [{\"icon_id\": 108, \"action_id\": 13121, \"trigger_id\": 11744, \"application\": null, \"guideline_ids\": null, \"drug_report_icon_id\": 108, \"trigger_phenotype_id\": null, \"metabolic_phenotype_id\": null, \"custom_drug_report",
    "alg_input_json": "{\"cap\": \"9432670\", \"npi\": \"1669836227\", \"nys\": null, \"clia\": \"24D2109855\", \"task\": \"7102C\", \"tube\": \"41211111706664\", \"target\": {\"F2\": {\"value\": \"rs1799963 GG\", \"value_raw\": null, \"phenotype_raw\": null, \"review_reasons\": [], \"phenotype_title\": null, \"value_functional\": \"rs1799963 GG\", \"phenotype_summary\": null, \"performing_site_indicator\": false}, \"F5\": {\"value\": \"rs6025 GG\", \"value_raw\": null, \"phenotype_raw\": null, \"review_reasons\": [], \"phenotype_title\": null, \"value_functional\": \"rs6025 GG\", \"phenotype_summary\": null, \"performing_site_indicator\": false}, \"4F2\": {\"value\": \"*1/*3\", \"value_raw\": null, \"phenotype_raw\": null, \"review_reasons\": [], \"phenotype_title\": null, \"value_functional\": \"*1/*3\", \"phenotype_summary\": null, \"performing_site_indicator\": false}, \"COMT\": {\"value\": \"rs4680 GA\", \"value_raw\": null, \"phenotype_raw\": null, \"review_reasons\": [], \"phenotype_title\": null, \"value_functional\": \"rs4680 GA\", \"phenotype_summary\": null, \"performing_site_indicator\": false}, \"DPYD\": {\""
  },
  {
    "id": 76297,
    "uuid": "0x14F1553B726C11ED8131F9590B4EAE8C",
    "sf_id": null,
    "sf_sync_date": null,
    "mtime": "2022-12-08T17:28:17",
    "ctime": "2022-12-02T18:06:45",
    "kit_id": 98584,
    "report_json": "{\"drugs\": {\"Codeine\": {\"bin\": \"R\", \"name\": \"Codeine\", \"icons\": [108, 93, 103], \"drug_id\": 36, \"pathway\": {\"code\": \"prodrug\", \"text\": \"is **inactive**, its metabolites are active.\"}, \"targets\": [\"OPRM1\"], \"loe_code\": \"1A\", \"triggers\": [{\"actions\": [{\"icon_id\": 103, \"action_id\": 14915, \"trigger_id\": 12036, \"application\": null, \"guideline_ids\": \"887\", \"drug_report_icon_id\": 103, \"trigger_phenotype_id\": null, \"metabolic_phenotype_id\": null, \"custom_drug_report_text\": null}], \"drug_id\": 36, \"proceed\": true, \"sort_key\": 100049, \"conditions\": [{\"gene_id\": null, \"allele_id\": null, \"trigger_id\": 12036, \"condition_id\": 105207, \"ethnicity_id\": null, \"drug_phenotype_id\": null, \"gene_phenotype_id\": null}], \"trigger_id\": 12036, \"icon_block_level\": 0, \"guideline_block_level\": 0}, {\"actions\": [{\"icon_id\": 108, \"action_id\": 13121, \"trigger_id\": 11744, \"application\": null, \"guideline_ids\": null, \"drug_report_icon_id\": 108, \"trigger_phenotype_id\": null, \"metabolic_phenotype_id\": null, \"custom_drug_report",
    "alg_input_json": "{\"cap\": \"9432670\", \"npi\": \"1669836227\", \"nys\": null, \"clia\": \"24D2109855\", \"task\": \"46CD1\", \"tube\": \"41220410301285\", \"target\": {\"F2\": {\"value\": \"rs1799963 GG\", \"value_raw\": null, \"phenotype_raw\": null, \"review_reasons\": [], \"phenotype_title\": null, \"value_functional\": \"rs1799963 GG\", \"phenotype_summary\": null, \"performing_site_indicator\": false}, \"F5\": {\"value\": \"rs6025 GG\", \"value_raw\": null, \"phenotype_raw\": null, \"review_reasons\": [], \"phenotype_title\": null, \"value_functional\": \"rs6025 GG\", \"phenotype_summary\": null, \"performing_site_indicator\": false}, \"4F2\": {\"value\": \"*1/*3\", \"value_raw\": null, \"phenotype_raw\": null, \"review_reasons\": [], \"phenotype_title\": null, \"value_functional\": \"*1/*3\", \"phenotype_summary\": null, \"performing_site_indicator\": false}, \"COMT\": {\"value\": \"rs4680 GA\", \"value_raw\": null, \"phenotype_raw\": null, \"review_reasons\": [], \"phenotype_title\": null, \"value_functional\": \"rs4680 GA\", \"phenotype_summary\": null, \"performing_site_indicator\": false}, \"DPYD\": {\""
  },
  {
    "id": 76298,
    "uuid": "0x1E57384A726C11EDBD0AF9590B4EAE8C",
    "sf_id": null,
    "sf_sync_date": null,
    "mtime": "2022-12-08T17:05:32",
    "ctime": "2022-12-02T18:07:01",
    "kit_id": 98584,
    "report_json": "{\"drugs\": {}, \"genes\": {\"MTHFR\": {\"name\": \"MTHFR\", \"type\": \"target\", \"value\": \"rs1801131 AA, rs1801133 CT\", \"hidden\": false, \"alleles\": null, \"gene_id\": 97, \"sort_key\": 0, \"description\": \"Note: MTHFR is available to providers as an optional, complimentary add-on to the RightMed Test. MTHFR is not available to patients who purchase the test online (ordered through the independent physician network).\\n\\nResiding on the minus strand of chromosome 1, the <em>MTHFR</em> gene encodes the rate-limiting enzyme methylenetetrahydrofolate reductase. This enzyme is integrally involved in the DNA synthesis pathway, specifically in the conversion of homocysteine to methionine through the methylation cycle of folic acid. Common variants in this gene, namely rs1801133 and rs1801131, can disrupt this pathway, thereby altering folic acid metabolism and/or leading to hyperhomocysteinemia. However, the American College of Medical Genetics and Genomics (ACMG) determined that <em>MTHFR</em> genotyping has m",
    "alg_input_json": "{\"cap\": \"9432670\", \"npi\": \"1669836227\", \"nys\": null, \"clia\": \"24D2109855\", \"task\": \"46CD1\", \"tube\": \"41220410301285\", \"target\": {\"MTHFR\": {\"value\": \"rs1801131 AA, rs1801133 CT\", \"value_raw\": null, \"phenotype_raw\": null, \"review_reasons\": [], \"phenotype_title\": null, \"value_functional\": \"rs1801131 AA, rs1801133 CT\", \"phenotype_summary\": null, \"performing_site_indicator\": false}}, \"patient\": {\"dob\": \"1938-05-22\", \"name\": \"Rosa Del Carmen Valero\", \"ethnicity\": 50, \"sample_id\": null, \"identifier\": \"41220410301285\"}, \"filename\": null, \"provider\": \"Dra. Leticia Aguilar\", \"metabolic\": {}, \"exceptions\": null, \"panel_code\": \"SG-MTHFR\", \"translator\": null, \"report_type\": null, \"sample_type\": \"Buccal swab\", \"deidentified\": false, \"lab_comments\": \"\", \"lab_director\": \"Lee Kaplan, PhD, FACMG\", \"product_code\": \"SG-MTHFR\", \"receive_date\": \"2022-11-29\", \"report_state\": null, \"report_title\": null, \"specimen_date\": null, \"collection_date\": \"2022-11-17\", \"institution_code\": null, \"ordering_facility\": \"Dra"
  },
  {
    "id": 76299,
    "uuid": "0x27E1EE28726C11ED80593B7BF98F6338",
    "sf_id": null,
    "sf_sync_date": null,
    "mtime": "2022-12-02T18:08:09",
    "ctime": "2022-12-02T18:07:17",
    "kit_id": 92604,
    "report_json": "{\"drugs\": {\"Aspirin\": {\"bin\": \"X\", \"name\": \"Aspirin\", \"icons\": [], \"drug_id\": 901, \"pathway\": {\"code\": \"unknown\", \"text\": \"oneome-unclassified-do-not-use or gray drug\"}, \"targets\": [], \"loe_code\": \"4\", \"triggers\": [{\"actions\": [{\"icon_id\": null, \"action_id\": 14962, \"trigger_id\": 12050, \"application\": null, \"guideline_ids\": null, \"drug_report_icon_id\": 84, \"trigger_phenotype_id\": null, \"metabolic_phenotype_id\": null, \"custom_drug_report_text\": \"Several studies have shown that the pharmacokinetic properties, risk of aspirin related toxic events, and treatment efficacy of aspirin are not significantly impacted by CYP2C9. Preliminary evidence suggests that PEAR1 rs12041331 may modulate non-COX dependent platelet aggregation pathways, but there is no evidence to suggest an association between the variant and adverse drug events while taking aspirin. In a study with 895 Danish patients with stable coronary artery disease taking 75mg aspirin daily, patients homozygous AA or heterozygous GA fo",
    "alg_input_json": "{\"cap\": \"9432670\", \"npi\": \"1669836227\", \"nys\": null, \"clia\": \"24D2109855\", \"task\": \"9AB93\", \"tube\": \"41220111302721\", \"target\": {\"F2\": {\"value\": \"rs1799963 GG\", \"value_raw\": null, \"phenotype_raw\": null, \"review_reasons\": [], \"phenotype_title\": null, \"value_functional\": \"rs1799963 GG\", \"phenotype_summary\": null, \"performing_site_indicator\": false}, \"F5\": {\"value\": \"rs6025 GG\", \"value_raw\": null, \"phenotype_raw\": null, \"review_reasons\": [], \"phenotype_title\": null, \"value_functional\": \"rs6025 GG\", \"phenotype_summary\": null, \"performing_site_indicator\": false}, \"4F2\": {\"value\": \"*3/*3\", \"value_raw\": null, \"phenotype_raw\": null, \"review_reasons\": [], \"phenotype_title\": null, \"value_functional\": \"*3/*3\", \"phenotype_summary\": null, \"performing_site_indicator\": false}, \"COMT\": {\"value\": \"rs4680 GA\", \"value_raw\": null, \"phenotype_raw\": null, \"review_reasons\": [], \"phenotype_title\": null, \"value_functional\": \"rs4680 GA\", \"phenotype_summary\": null, \"performing_site_indicator\": false}, \"DPYD\": {\""
  },
  {
    "id": 76300,
    "uuid": "0x3E3C4E93726C11EDAD13F9590B4EAE8C",
    "sf_id": null,
    "sf_sync_date": null,
    "mtime": "2022-12-02T18:08:49",
    "ctime": "2022-12-02T18:07:54",
    "kit_id": 104289,
    "report_json": "{\"drugs\": {\"Aspirin\": {\"bin\": \"X\", \"name\": \"Aspirin\", \"icons\": [], \"drug_id\": 901, \"pathway\": {\"code\": \"unknown\", \"text\": \"oneome-unclassified-do-not-use or gray drug\"}, \"targets\": [], \"loe_code\": \"4\", \"triggers\": [{\"actions\": [{\"icon_id\": null, \"action_id\": 14962, \"trigger_id\": 12050, \"application\": null, \"guideline_ids\": null, \"drug_report_icon_id\": 84, \"trigger_phenotype_id\": null, \"metabolic_phenotype_id\": null, \"custom_drug_report_text\": \"Several studies have shown that the pharmacokinetic properties, risk of aspirin related toxic events, and treatment efficacy of aspirin are not significantly impacted by CYP2C9. Preliminary evidence suggests that PEAR1 rs12041331 may modulate non-COX dependent platelet aggregation pathways, but there is no evidence to suggest an association between the variant and adverse drug events while taking aspirin. In a study with 895 Danish patients with stable coronary artery disease taking 75mg aspirin daily, patients homozygous AA or heterozygous GA fo",
    "alg_input_json": "{\"cap\": \"9432670\", \"npi\": \"1669836227\", \"nys\": null, \"clia\": \"24D2109855\", \"task\": \"1C887\", \"tube\": \"41220611601491\", \"target\": {\"F2\": {\"value\": \"rs1799963 GG\", \"value_raw\": null, \"phenotype_raw\": null, \"review_reasons\": [], \"phenotype_title\": null, \"value_functional\": \"rs1799963 GG\", \"phenotype_summary\": null, \"performing_site_indicator\": false}, \"F5\": {\"value\": \"rs6025 GG\", \"value_raw\": null, \"phenotype_raw\": null, \"review_reasons\": [], \"phenotype_title\": null, \"value_functional\": \"rs6025 GG\", \"phenotype_summary\": null, \"performing_site_indicator\": false}, \"4F2\": {\"value\": \"*1/*1\", \"value_raw\": null, \"phenotype_raw\": null, \"review_reasons\": [], \"phenotype_title\": null, \"value_functional\": \"*1/*1\", \"phenotype_summary\": null, \"performing_site_indicator\": false}, \"COMT\": {\"value\": \"rs4680 GA\", \"value_raw\": null, \"phenotype_raw\": null, \"review_reasons\": [], \"phenotype_title\": null, \"value_functional\": \"rs4680 GA\", \"phenotype_summary\": null, \"performing_site_indicator\": false}, \"DPYD\": {\""
  },
  {
    "id": 76301,
    "uuid": "0x472B379C726C11ED9066F9590B4EAE8C",
    "sf_id": null,
    "sf_sync_date": null,
    "mtime": "2022-12-02T18:08:52",
    "ctime": "2022-12-02T18:08:09",
    "kit_id": 104289,
    "report_json": "{\"drugs\": {}, \"genes\": {\"MTHFR\": {\"name\": \"MTHFR\", \"type\": \"target\", \"value\": \"rs1801131 AA, rs1801133 TT\", \"hidden\": false, \"alleles\": null, \"gene_id\": 97, \"sort_key\": 0, \"description\": \"Note: MTHFR is available to providers as an optional, complimentary add-on to the RightMed Test. MTHFR is not available to patients who purchase the test online (ordered through the independent physician network).\\n\\nResiding on the minus strand of chromosome 1, the <em>MTHFR</em> gene encodes the rate-limiting enzyme methylenetetrahydrofolate reductase. This enzyme is integrally involved in the DNA synthesis pathway, specifically in the conversion of homocysteine to methionine through the methylation cycle of folic acid. Common variants in this gene, namely rs1801133 and rs1801131, can disrupt this pathway, thereby altering folic acid metabolism and/or leading to hyperhomocysteinemia. However, the American College of Medical Genetics and Genomics (ACMG) determined that <em>MTHFR</em> genotyping has m",
    "alg_input_json": "{\"cap\": \"9432670\", \"npi\": \"1669836227\", \"nys\": null, \"clia\": \"24D2109855\", \"task\": \"1C887\", \"tube\": \"41220611601491\", \"target\": {\"MTHFR\": {\"value\": \"rs1801131 AA, rs1801133 TT\", \"value_raw\": null, \"phenotype_raw\": null, \"review_reasons\": [], \"phenotype_title\": null, \"value_functional\": \"rs1801131 AA, rs1801133 TT\", \"phenotype_summary\": null, \"performing_site_indicator\": false}}, \"patient\": {\"dob\": \"1966-10-11\", \"name\": \"Paula Dunham\", \"ethnicity\": 70, \"sample_id\": null, \"identifier\": \"\"}, \"filename\": null, \"provider\": \"Melissa Turner\", \"metabolic\": {}, \"exceptions\": null, \"panel_code\": \"SG-MTHFR\", \"translator\": null, \"report_type\": null, \"sample_type\": \"Buccal swab\", \"deidentified\": false, \"lab_comments\": \"\", \"lab_director\": \"Lee Kaplan, PhD, FACMG\", \"product_code\": \"SG-MTHFR\", \"receive_date\": \"2022-11-28\", \"report_state\": null, \"report_title\": null, \"specimen_date\": null, \"collection_date\": \"2022-11-23\", \"institution_code\": null, \"ordering_facility\": \"Tarheel PGx Consulting, LLC\", \"la"
  }
```

Comment: The error suggests your JSON isn't formatted correctly, can you post it?

Comment: The data is huge and is in json column

Comment: is there a. way i can find erroring json record or eliminate this error somehow

Comment: I hope this site help you : https://copyprogramming.com/howto/sql-server-json-text-is-not-properly-formatted-unexpected-character-found-at-position-0 
 .if you show json in post ,we can help you

Comment: added json column sample please help

Comment: The json in your question is missing the closing `]`. Other than that, it's valid json. Is the omission of `]` a typo or is it missing in the actual data?

Comment: Every single one of the `report_json` and `alg_input_json` properties in your example contain nested JSON (JSON-encoded JSON) that's truncated and doesn't contain balanced braces `{}`. It seems that you have broken/incomplete JSON data sources.

Comment: You could skip the malformed json with isjson() (or use it to find the problematic rows) `.. APPLY OPENJSON(case when isjson(cr.report_json)=1 then cr.report_json end, '$.drugs') d ...`

Answer (score 0):

Answer by @lptr in a comment:

---

You have malformed nested JSON. You could skip the malformed json with `isjson()` (or use it to find the problematic rows)

```
...
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CASE WHEN ISJSON(cr.report_json) = 1 THEN cr.report_json END, '$.drugs') d
...
```